# how to know an activity lifecycle method has finished running

Tags: android, unit-testing, robotium

I am using Robotium Solo for activity testing

i need to know that onCreate has finished running before i proceed with my test

i can tell it to sleep for 5 seconds, but that wont help, because i need the first row of onStart to be caught, and onCreate finishes at different times each time

how do i tell solo to wait until onCreate has finished?

this is what my code looks like :

```
solo.sleep(5000);

    solo.clickOnButton("animate");
    solo.sleep(5000);

    solo.clickOnButton("close");
    solo.sleep(5000);

    solo.clickOnButton("animate");
    solo.sleep(5000);

    solo.clickOnButton("close");
    solo.sleep(5000);

    solo.clickOnButton("animate");
    solo.sleep(5000);

    solo.clickOnButton("close");
    solo.sleep(5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add another method to search your controls to your code. For example:

```
static boolean clickOnButton(String name, Solo solo){
    Button view = null;
    try{
            ArrayList<Button> temp = solo.getCurrentViews(Button.class);
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
                if (temp.get(i).getText().toString().equals(name)){
                    view = temp.get(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
            view.click();
            return true;
    } catch (Error err) {
            return false;
    } 
}
```

If you are sure that the button will exist, you could loop such search, add some flag, make do-while cycle and change the flag by condition

```
    if (view == null)
```

Comment: that wasn't my problem - that my view was null, however this answer does answer a different question i had - so i accept it anyway ;) thanks!

Comment: There is solo.waitForActivity() method. Try to use it to solve your problem. I've tried to use this method and my tests becomes too slow (for me, because even one excess delay second was not acceptable for me. It took about 2 seconds). So, perhaps it waits until OnCreate() is finished. Experiment with it )))